# Minimal directed circles partition cover of a directed graph

Tags: ds.algorithms

We are given a $G(V,E)$ digraph and a $c:E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ weight function. We are searching for a set of $C_{1}(V_{1},E_{1}),C_{2}(V_{2},E_{2}),\ldots,C_{k}(V_{k},E_{k})$ directed circles such that $V_{1},\ldots,V_{k}$ form a partition of $V$ and $\sum_{i = 1}^{k}\sum_{e \in E_{i}}c(e)$ is minimal among all such covers.

I know there is a polynomial algorithm which solves this problem. I just don't know what that algorithm is. Anyone knows this problem and can give a hint or a solution?(hint preferred)

Comment: cstheory.stackexchange.com is for research-level questions and not for homework help.

Comment: I thought it's a Q&A site for questions in the cs topic.

Comment: This website is for research-level questions in theoretical computer science.  [“Typical homework problems in textbooks” are off-topic here](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/235#235).  This question is at the level of typical homework problems in textbooks.

Comment: If this is a typical homework level question can you give a short hint on how to solve it?

Comment: I will not give a hint because (1) I am afraid that giving a hint to this question may encourage other people to ask questions at the same level, and (2) for this problem, I find it difficult to give a hint without giving the solution.

Comment: I second Tsuyoshi. Homework questions are not welcome here. If you want a solution for such a problem, look at textbooks or ask your course instructor/TA. Also note that in most universities, getting help in solving assignments and presenting work which is not yours can have heavy punishments. I discourage anyone from answering homework questions, specially from new/low reputation users using nicknames.

Comment: I won't present this work since the deadline has passed. I was just interested in the solution. That's why I asked it...

Comment: You could have asked your course instructor/TA for a solution.

Comment: Yeah but the next class is on next friday.

Comment: I have to disagree. I think many people do not know about min-cost flow since it is not a standard topic covered in standard algorithms class.

Comment: @Sariel: What is the _easiest_ solution depends on how your learn these algorithms, but in my opinion, reducing this problem to the minimum-cost flow is a more complicated way to solve it than necessary.  In fact, if it required the minimum-cost flow, I might not have voted to close this question.

Comment: @Sariel: By the way, if you would like to discuss more about closing/reopening, please start a thread on [Meta](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/).  Continuing a discussion in comments is not recommended.

Comment: @Sariel Har-Peled: I am just guessing, but I think the instructor had thought that students can solve it based on the material covered in the course. Btw, there is a meta-discussion on [homework questions](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/209/homework-or-things-that-look-like-homework). (ps: I found the book very interesting, thanks for the link.)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi. Exactly my point. If there is a solution that does not use min cost flow (or circulations), I would like to know about it.

Comment: You can use something somewhat simpler than flow/circulations, namely matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done by using minimum cost flow. See section 17.4 [here](http://valis.cs.uiuc.edu/~sariel/teach/notes/algos/lec/17_flow_mc_II.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. The text is clear and I stand stupid. Sorry for bothering everyone with questions like this.